# How to use cubic-bezier to change the speed of a keyframe animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to create a `@keyframe` animation to bring a box up from the bottom of the screen and then have it bounce off the top of the body of the HTML document. The method that I used to do this doesn't allow you to change the speed during the duration of the animation which intern doesn't make it look very realistic (**See Code Below**).

I have found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29786270/4700944) to my question the only problem is that I really don't understand how `cubic-bezier` is creating the animation. I would like to make sense of what the code is doing before I go ahead and just slap it into my project. So, yeah I guess the title of this question shouldn't be **"How to use cubic-bezier to change the speed of a keyframe animation?"** but **"How does the cubic-bezier work and how is it working in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29786270/4700944) instance"**. I would absolutely appreciate it if someone could explain this a little and even give me a simple example of code to follow and understand.

**Note:** I have looked at [Mozila Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function) at this property and still don't fully understand how it works in or out of a `@keyframe` animation.

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#square').className = 'bounce';
  document.querySelector('#square').style.display = 'block';
});
document.querySelector('#square').addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
  if (e.animationName == 'animate-in') {
    document.querySelector('#square').removeAttribute('class');
  }
});
```

```css
#button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
}

#square {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: tomato;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.bounce {
  animation: animate-in 1.5s;
}

@keyframes animate-in {
  20%,
  50%,
  80%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100vh);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="Run Animation">
<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: You may want to use this site which visualises how the cubic-bezier actually works: http://cubic-bezier.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find by playing with the box on here https://matthewlein.com/ceaser/ that you get a decent understanding of cubic bezier.

Imagine a box. If you place a marker on:
bottom left corner of the box, it has a value of (0)
top right corner of the box, it has a value of (1)

But there are 4 values for cubic bezier e.g....
cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);

That is because there are in effect two markers (or start points).

The first two values are obtained from a starting point of the *bottom left* corner of the box, of which the value is (0,0). As you move the marker to the *right*, the first value changes, e.g.(*0.755*, 0.000). As you move the marker *up* the second value changes e.g.(0.755, *0.050*).

The second two values are obtained by a starting point of *top right* of a box, of which the value is (1,1). As you move the marker to the *left*, the third value changes, e.g.(*0.855*, 1.000). As you move the marker *down* the fourth value changes e.g.(0.855, *0.060*).

Values one and three (left and right) control the time, values two and four (up and down) control the animation.

Putting these values together makes (0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);

I have included a diagram (it does not show the same values as the example above) but should help to understand the information above.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Thanks so much I am starting to understand it. Correct me if I am wrong but can `cubic-bezier` only be used with the `transition-timing-function`?

Comment: Check out https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp for more info. It states you can use animation-timing-function: linear|ease|ease-in|ease-out|ease-in-out|step-start|step-end|steps(int,start|end)|cubic-bezier(n,n,n,n)|initial|inherit;